# Erro no algoritmo Bubble Sort em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, estrutura-de-dados, bubblesort

Atualmente tenho estudado um pouco Python e, em meio aos estudos estou tentando realizar um desafio onde
preciso implementar um algoritmo do Bubble Sort em Python.
Os critérios são:

1. O algoritmo recebe recebe uma string como entrada e ordena os valores informados.
2. Esta string deve ser separada por espaços em branco
3. Entrada: ‘10 8 2 3 5 1’
   Saída: ‘1 2 3 5 8 10’

Eu implementei o algoritmo abaixo, porém o que tenho recebido como saída é:
['1', '10', '2', '3', '5', '8']

Eu não consigo ver o erro na minha lógica, se alguém puder me ajudar como solucionar isto e apontar onde estar meu erro eu agradeço.

> ```
> def sort(array):
>
>     for final in range(len(array), 0, -1):
>         exchanging = False
>
>         for current in range(0, final - 1):
>             if array[current] > array[current + 1]:
>                 array[current + 1], array[current] = array[current], array[current + 1]
>                 exchanging = True
>
>         if not exchanging:
>             break
>
> array = sorted(['10', '8', '2', '3', '5', '1']) # entrada: 10 8 2 3 5 1 saída: ‘1 2 3 5 8 10’
> sort(array)
> print(array)
> ```

Answer (score 1):

O seu código está correto, o problema é que você está usando strings. Strings não são comparadas numericamente e sim alfabeticamente, porque podem conter letras e outros caracteres... Então `'10'` é realmente menor que `'2'`, assim como `'ba'` é menor que `'c'`.

Sendo assim, a ordem está correta, textualmente... Se você quer comparar o valor numérico, teria que usar inteiros, por exemplo:

```
if int(array[current]) > int(array[current + 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Se você deseja **ordenar valores** não faz sentido capturar `strings`. Por isso é mais cômodo capturar diretamente o valor numérico.

Percebi que os valores que você está trabalhando são inteiros, então desenvolvi o seguinte algoritmo para resolver sua questão...

```
# Algoritmo de ordenação "Bubble Sort".
def bubble_sort(array):
    fim = len(array)
    while fim > 0:
        i = 0
        # Percorrendo o vetor de "0" até "fim".
        while i < fim - 1:
            # Realizando a troca da posição atual pela próxima.
            if array[i] > array[i + 1]:
                temp = array[i]
                array[i] = array[i + 1]
                array[i + 1] = temp
            i += 1
        fim -= 1
    print(f'\033[32mO vetor ordenado é: {array}')


vetor = [10, 8, 2, 3, 5, 1]
bubble_sort(vetor)
print()
```

Observe que este algoritmo está trabalhando com uma lista `fixa`, de números inteiros, que no caso é ...

```
vetor = [10, 8, 2, 3, 5, 1]
```

Observe também que este algoritmo percorre a lista dada e, em seguida, ordena os seus valores inteiros.

Agora, se você deseja executar `bubble sort` em quaisquer listas, você pode utilizar o seguinte algoritmo...

```
# Algoritmo de ordenação "Bubble Sort".
def bubble_sort(array):
    fim = len(array)
    while fim > 0:
        i = 0
        # Percorrendo o vetor de "0" até "fim".
        while i < fim - 1:
            # Realizando a troca da posição atual pela próxima.
            if array[i] > array[i + 1]:
                temp = array[i]
                array[i] = array[i + 1]
                array[i + 1] = temp
            i += 1
        fim -= 1
    print(f'\033[32mO vetor ordenado é: {array}')


vetor = list(map(int, input('Digite os valores do array: ').split()))
bubble_sort(vetor)
print()
```

Neste segundo algoritmo é solicitado para digitar os valores do respectivo vetor.

**OBSERVAÇÃO**: No momento da solicitação dos valores, você tem que digitar **todos** os valores na mesma linha do `input`, separados por `um só espaço`. Depois de digitar todos os valores, pressione a tecla `Enter`.

Neste momento o algoritmo realizará toda a tarefa de ordenação.

Answer (score -1):

Eu fiz assim

```
def swap( array, i, j ):
    tmp = array[ i ]
    array[ i ] = array[ j ]
    array[ j ] = tmp

def bubble( array ):
    for i in range( 0, len( array ) ):
        for j in range( len( array ), i + 1, -1 ):
            if array[ j ] > array[ j - 1]:
                swap( array, j, j - 1 )
```